# import js module in js file in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I've started a project with the new [vue-cli 3.0](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and I've added the [qwery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qwery) npm module in node package.json

```
npm i qwery
```

and in `my-file.js` which is at same level as `main.js` I import it the following way:

```
import {qwery as $q} from "qwery"
```

The build goes ok however in the browser `$q` is `undefined` and webpack has imported it as `qwery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__`.

Clearly I'm not doing it the right way can somebody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import it like this

```
import $q from 'qwery';
```

Comment: 10x it does work. Somehow magically because I don't see no `$q` in closure when debugging in browser. Why is that no idea?

Comment: if you want to create a global ref to `$q` just add `window.$q = $q;` under that import statement.